# How do I view coordinates in Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a way to view my current coordinates in Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition? People keep saying to use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, but that just opens a new Google Chrome tab.

I've been searching the internet for hours and I'm kinda desperate, because I want to use the cheats I haven't been able to use ever before and I need the coordinates to do that. I've tried:

- Maps
- Using <kbd>F3</kbd>
- Using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
- Using a compass and a map crafted together
  !

Comment: Have you tried just f3?

Comment: yeah, nothing happened.

Comment: This is why we use the original!

Answer (score 12):

Do `/gamerule showcoordinates true`

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: this isn't working... i accidentally hit some key which hid coordinates... the game rule is still true.  how do i "unhide" them?

Answer (score 10):

As of now the only way to get coordinates without addons is to enable commands. then you can use

```
/tp ~ ~ ~
```

this will teleport you to the same location you are at, but will send a message with your current coordinates. I just tested it, and it works.

Supposedly you can also use [his addon](http://mcpedl.com/coordinates-unlocker-addon/) to display coordinates in the lower right corner. I have not tested the addon.

---

#### EDIT: It has been added as a world config option in a recent version.

This answer will be left as-is because of historical reasons (i.e. someone is using an old version).

Answer (score 4):

The Windows 10 version of Minecraft is a port of Minecraft: Pocket Edition, which unfortunately has no F3 debug screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the windows-10 edition of minecraft, it might be as simple as they haven't added that feature of the game to it yet (I do not own the Windows 10 edition, so I wouldn't know for sure). Usually, the default key for displaying the coords and other info is 'F3'.

This could also be an issue with your controls not being set to display the debug overlay in-game. If this is the case, it's a tiny bit more in-depth. type %appdata% into windows file explorer navigation bar and press ENTER. open the .minecraft folder and open options.txt with notepad application. after this, locate the entry that says "Key_Debug Key:" and set its value to 68 . Make sure to SAVE the file after you close it. Relaunch minecraft  and go into your world and it will let you press F3 button and open the debug menu to get your coords.

This how to was based off of my knowledge of the original minecraft client acquired from minecraft.net

Answer (score 1):

Once your windows 10 game opens up, press play, then edit on the world you'd like to add coordinates on. On the first page that is opened it will say "Show Coordinates" and turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

You need this add-on, I tested it and the coordinates show up in the middle above the items.

http://mcpedl.com/coordinates-unlocker-addon/[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the windows 10 edition, you have go to the Run program on your computer, type in %appdata% then click on the .minecraft folder scroll down until you see options.txt.

Once you find that text file click on it until you see the "key_key" options. Now you won't see a debug option, so you have to make one.
To make one simply make a new line under the "key_key.attack" line
Then type "key_debug.key:68" then SAVE THAT text file, do not make a new one.

Just click "file" on the top left of the text screen, and then click save. Now you can close that widow out, and you should have coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Go to game settings and click the option for "show coordinates" to on.

If you do not want them on your screen all the time use Mindwins answer, type in /tp ~ ~ ~ and read the text for where you are.

Comment: I don't think this is applicable to the Win 10 edition

Answer (score 0):

To turn on coordinates, there are 2 options:

Option 1: go to your pause tab by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>. On your screen it should have 4 buttons: resume, settings, feedback, and save and quit. Click on settings and scroll down until you find "show coordinates". Click the on/off button beside it. You're done!

Option 2: press `/` and your chat should open up. Type `/gamerule showcoordinates true`. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You're finished!